# Efficiency of custom comparators

Tags: java, performance, comparator

Which of these two custom comparators is the most efficient? (Used on a vector of thousands of arrays)

```
//Compares arrays by their first element, then second if equal
Comparator<String[]> comparator = new Comparator<String[]>() {
        public int compare(String[] c1, String[] c2) {
            int comparison; 
            if((comparison=(c1[0].compareTo(c2[0])))==0) return c1[1].compareTo(c2[1]);
            else return comparison;
        }
};

//Compares arrays by their first element, then second if equal
Comparator<String[]> comparator = new Comparator<String[]>() {
        public int compare(String[] c1, String[] c2) {
            if(c1[0].compareTo(c2[0])==0) return c1[1].compareTo(c2[1]);
            else return c1[0].compareTo(c2[0]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking them?

Comment: Or seeing if these even get compiled into different byte code?

Comment: Maybe you should go ask that on code-review? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unfortunately benchmarking/testing is limited since it used on a millions of users. I was hoping for an answer from a theory side.

Comment: Well from theory the first one should be faster as it has one call less by buffering the comparison result.

Comment: @1337 Thanks! I didn't know the existence of it!

Comment: I don't understand how "millions of users" limits benchmarking. Design an experiment!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is more efficient, because in case the first element differs you return the result of that comparison instead comparing again like in the second, thus saving one comparison. Strictly by the principle "less work done = less execution time spent".

That said, String.compare() is pretty fast if the strings aren't very long and share a common prefix. So you may not see a difference in practice.

Comment: @lolkidoki This doesn't mean that efficiency requires strange coding like assignments in conditions. Note that you haven't saved a single character by doing this.